Anycubic Kobra 2 Neo not printing layers correctly
I've got the Anycubic Kobra 2 Neo, and the second layer isn't printing correctly, it's bubbling up and not fusing with the first layer properly. I've tried adjust the heat, recalibrating, and I tried 3 different filaments. Can you help me?


Hi, welcome to 3DPrinting.SE! Please provide additional information, e.g. temperatures, speeds, material, etc. It looks like the second layer is completely molten. Do you have an image where the print hasn't been taken from the build plate, or didn't it stick?

Your question is lacking detail and as such is hard to answer without knowing a couple of things about your printer setup. Please [edit] and fill in the [placeholders] in the template I added and then remove the leading <!-- and trailing --> afterwards. This will turn it visible and help us help you find the actual problem.
